# Generate unique 16 character strings across multiple runs

Tags: c#, hash, unique

I have to generate 16 character strings, about 1,00,000 a month. They should be such that they don't repeat across multiple runs (once a month, every month). What is the best method to achieve this? Is using hash functions a good idea?
The string can have A-Z and 0-9 only.
This is to be done using C#.
EDIT: The strings should be random. So, keeping a simple counter is not an option.

Comment: What characters will be allowed in the strings? E.g. if the only characters allowed are "1" and "0", then there are only 65536 possible strings in total. If it's any unicode character, there's a lot more range.

Comment: you didn't say anything about the requirements. Should they be cryptographically secure? Because you could simply have a counter and output "0000000000000001, 0000000000000002" etc...

Comment: Things like languages should be included in the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're limited to 16 alphanumeric characters, a GUID is probably not an option - it requires the full 128 bits to be unique and whilst that will generate a 16 character string, it will not necessarily fit the alphanumeric constraint.

You could have a simple counter and return the last 64 bits of an MD5 hash and check for uniqueness each time.

```
//parse out hex digits in calling code
static long NextHash(HashSet<long> hashes, int count)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    long l = BitConverter.ToInt64(md5.ComputeHash(IntToArray(count)));
    if(!hashes.Contains(l)){
        hashes.Add(l);
        return l;
    } else return -1; //check this in calling code for failure
}
static byte[] IntToArray(int i)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    bytes[j] = (byte)i;
    i>>=8;    
    }
}
```

You could do something similar for GUIDS, but I don't know how likely collisions are when you're only looking at a substring.
MD5 hashes have the advantage of "appearing" more random, if that's at all relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the language.

PHP,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

```
echo rand(0,999).uniqid();
rand(0,999) = 3 characters randomly
uniqid() = 13 randomly characters
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that satisfies you, but I came up with sth like that

```
static List<string> generate(int count)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    while (strings.Count < count)
    {
        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();                
        string GuidString = g.ToString();
        GuidString = GuidString.Replace("-", "");
        GuidString = GuidString.Remove(16);
        if (!strings.Contains(GuidString))
            strings.Add(GuidString);
    }
    return strings;
}
```